# Build Python with static openssl

Tags: python, openssl, rpmbuild

I need to build a Python 3.7.1 RPM for work. It looks 3.7.1 requires OpenSSL 1.1.1 so if I first build OpenSSL 1.1.1 in /usr then build Python 3.7.1 in /usr everything works on the build system. If I package the RPM and install it on another machine I get complaints about missing OpenSSL.

So I built an OpenSSL 1.1.1 RPM but there are too many conflicts with other packages so here is what I would LIKE to do. Please tell me if this is doable.

Compile Python 3.7.1 with OpenSSL 1.1.1 built statically so that it doesn't need to be installed everywhere I install the RPM.

Answer (score 0):

Give https://github.com/chevah/pythia a try. It doesn't package the resulting file as RPM, but otherwise it does what it is required.

Using `alien`, you should be able to package the resulting `.tar.gz` file as RPM, but I haven't tried it…